# Let A be an $n×n$ matrix. If $A,u,v$ have real entries, show that $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are solutions of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let A be an $n×n$ matrix. If $A,u,v$ have real entries, show that $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are solutions of the differential equation $x'(t)=Ax(t)$ provided that $u(t)+iv(t)$ is a solution.

My attempt:
Since $u(t)+iv(t)$ is a solution, then it satisfies the differential equation.

Let $v(t)=0$, then it follows $u(t)$ is a solution.

Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

No, since you can not assume that $v(t)=0$. Instead you are supposed to ponder that with $z(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$ being a solution also $\bar z(t)=u(t)-iv(t)$ is a solution.

Comment: So, suppose that $\overline{z}(t)$ is a solution(which I can show), what I thought of is that I'll add and subtract the two of them. Then by the principle of superposition, the result will give me another solution which will follow that indeed $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are solutions. Am I right with this?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go.